# C: Strings "eating" the loops (maybe)

Tags: c

I have some exercises from school for practice at C and I've been working on them since yesterday, but I've been pretty stiff with a particular one.

In this programme, which it must be repeated up to 5 times or until the user fails to answer the "safety question":

the user must be asked 3 times tops for the password (initially "abc123"), If the user doesn't know the password, he must answer to a safety question ("What your favourite colour?" with the answer being "none") 2 times tops. If he/she doesn't answer correctly either on that, it should show "Acound locked." and the loop should be terminated, OR if he/she does know the answer of the safety question, then he/she types a new password, which should work for the rest of the loops.

But it seems like the strings are somehow "eating" some loops. I've used getchar() but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Also, I think I've made a mistake for the big do-while that needs to repeat itself 5 times.

What have I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>          
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char temp[7];
char CODE[7] = "abc123";
char pin[7]; 
char safepin[7];
char newpin[7];
int i=0, p=0, k=0;  

int main()
{

do{
    do{
        printf("GIVE PASSWORD:\n");
        scanf("%s", pin);
        i++;
       } while (i<3 && strcmp (pin, CODE) != 0);

    if (strcmp(pin, CODE) == 0)
       printf("W E L C O M E !\n");
    else
    {
          do{
            printf("What's your favourite colour?\n");
            scanf("%s", safepin);
            p++;
             } while (p<2 && strcmp (safepin, "none") != 0);

       if (strcmp(safepin, "none") == 0)
          {
              printf("Type a new password:\n");
              scanf("%s", newpin);
              strcpy(temp, newpin);
              strcpy(CODE, temp);
              main();
          }
       else  
          printf("Account Locked\n");       

}
    printf("***************\n\n");
    k++;
}while(k<5);

system("pause");
return 0;     
}
```

UPDATE:

I modified the code a bit, thanks to the responses (you're all AMAZING) and it works like a charm, only it seems like when you have the right answer eventually, it keeps printing (GIVE PASSWORD) for ever, due to the first goto CHECKPOINT, not 5 times tops. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>          
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
int main()
{
char temp[7];
char CODE[7] = "abc123"; 
char pin[7];
char safepin[7];
char newpin[7];
int i=0, p=0, k=0;  
int verified = 0;
i = 0;
k = 0;

CHECKPOINT:

do{       
    do{ 
        printf("GIVE PASSWORD:\n");
        scanf("%s", pin);
        i++;
       } while (i<3 && strcmp (pin, CODE) != 0);

    if (strcmp(pin, CODE) == 0){
       printf("W E L C O M E !\n");
       verified = 1;
       goto CHECKPOINT;
       }
    else
    {             
          p = 0;
          do{
            printf("What's your favourite colour?\n");
            scanf("%s", safepin);
            p++;
             } while (p<2 && strcmp (safepin, "none") != 0);

          if (strcmp(safepin, "none") == 0)
          {
                printf("Type a new password:\n");
                scanf("%s", newpin);
                strcpy(temp, newpin);
                strcpy(CODE, temp);
                strcpy(pin, CODE);
                goto CHECKPOINT;
          }
          else  
                {
                printf("Account locked.\n");       
                verified = 1;
                }
    }
printf("***************\n\n");
k++;
}while(k<5 && !verified);

system("pause");
return 0;    
}
```

Comment: So when the user types his new password, immediately after the programme asking him to give the password. Since the password has changed, the password made by the user should work and then it shows "W E L C O M E !"

Comment: One thing I'm noticing in your assignment that I would change is the use of global variables for things that are really local to the routine.  If you were to later change main to a function like authenticate_user, these variables would not be reinitialized on reuse and worse would maintain sensitive information that would persist in the process and be available to the rest of the program or prying eyes that know how to inspect the address space of a running process.

Comment: When you say the strings appear to be "eating" your loops, exactly what do you mean?

Comment: I've been testing to put the variables in and out of the main(), but I think the problem is about the do-while loops.

Comment: When the first of the five total loops is done, the next time the "GIVE PASSWORD" thingy comes on only two times and the What's your favourite colour? one time.

Comment: If you want the counters to start over at 0, you need to reset them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this program the only thing that I notice is that the outer loop wants to repeat 5 times regardless.  You can remedy this by adding a flag named something like 'verified' or 'correct' (just use an int value) that is initialized to 0 and set to 1 at the same place you issue the W E L C O M E message.  Then change your outer look to include a check of this flag, e.g.

```
while(!verified && k<5)
```

Also, as I indicate in my comments I'd move all of the variable declarations along with their initializations inside the 'main'.  This way they are local to the routine and initialized at runtime instead of compile/link time.

Finally, while I realize this is an assignment and not a "real" security routine you are writing, for the sake of developing good pragmatic habits - I'd obiliterate (reinitialize) the variables, especially the one holding the verified password, immediately before exit to prevent their covert inspection by a skilled hacker later on.  This would never be advantageous for non-security related code even in production but are the kinds of things you have to think about when the code is a key security component.

I ran your program, and except for these things, it seems to work as advertised.

Comment: So I've made the "verified" flag but now, everytime i type a new password, it won't accept it afterwards. Only the first one (abc123).

Comment: UPDATE: Got able to surpass that by a goto CHECKPOINT inside the (if (strcmp(safepin, "none") == 0)) and a CHECKPOINT right after the variable declarations.

Comment: It would probably be good practice to refactor your code structure to get rid of the goto.  Your instructor may or may not have anything to say about gotos, but since Edsger W. Dijkstra's now famous (or infamous depending on your point of view) pronouncement (GO TO considered harmful) their use is very curtailed.  What ever you do though DO NOT EVER throw away a working program.  It is your ace-in-the-hole to turn in to get your assignment done on time.  I have been a software developer for >30 years and except for state machines I can count on one hand how many I have ever used.